# How to send a request to a docker image (grpc server) inside a docker-compose from an external machine?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, cloud

I want to host a service with a grpc interface on a cloud machine. The service consists of a docker-compose file. I need to access an image (in this case **worker**) inside the docker-compose from an outside machine. This image hosts a grpc server.

How do i make my network accessible from the outside and under what ip address do i send the request?
The network is already accessible when hosted on the same machine under localhost.

```
version: '2.3'

services:

  worker:
    image: 'image_taking_the_requests'
    networks:
      a_network:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.6
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 'true'
    depends_on:
      - model_server

  model_server:
    image: 'image_hosting_a_model'
    networks:
      a_network:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.7
    ports:
      - "8500:8501"

networks:
  a_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
```

Comment: What have you already tried?  You should be able to use the host's DNS name or IP address and the first number in `ports:` (8000).

Comment: Yes you are correct, i needed to open the port on my cloud machine. The container was already accessible.